# Where's the best SQLite 3 tutorial for iPhone-SDK?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm looking for an complete tutorial which not just tells me how an query is executed, but also how I set up the whole thing including setting up the library, creating an database, and so on.

Where can I find it?

Comment: iCodeBlog's has got a very well written tutorial on SQLite 3 as well.. Check out the first part at *[iPhone Programming Tutorial – Creating a ToDo List Using SQLite Part 1](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/)*.

Answer (score 11):

Using SQLite 3 on the iPhone is really not that different from using it on any other platform. You should read [the general SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html).

In your iPhone app, you usually open your SQLite database in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method  of your application delegate. After that, you can just use your database.

I've used [Gus Mueller's FMDatabase](http://www.gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2005/3/22.html) classes on the iPhone. They provide a thin wrapper around SQLite.

A final note: It seems [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coredata.html) will become available on the iPhone with OS version 3. You can use SQLite through the CoreData framework.

Answer (score 3):

**Stanfords cs193p *iPhone application development* previous semester showed how to setup and use sqlite3 with iphone.**

I haven't checked the latest lecture's but there is a reference to sqlite in latest semester. There are lecture notes and video in iTunesU - check out [cs193p web site](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) for links/references/example code/lecture notes.

Answer (score 2):

I have some iPhone [SQLite links](http://delicious.com/iggymwangi/SQLite) in my [Delicious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_%28website%29) bookmarks. There should be enough links there to teach you all the SQLite you will ever need. Lots of the tutorials are pretty simple and easy to understand. There are a few wrappers out there too. I haven't used any of the wrappers, but they look interesting. Also, check out other bookmarked items tagged SQLite on Delicious.

Comment: delicious link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Peter Quade's excellent answer, may I also suggest you to check out http://www.iphonekicks.com/tags/SQLite - here you would find many bookmarks to SQLite topics.

And just FYI, [iPhone Kicks](http://iphonekicks.com/) is a social book marking site, a [Digg](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:en.wikipedia.org%20digg%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) clone but purely for the iPhone SDK links :-)

Comment: The first link seems to be broken.