# Connect iphone app to mysql data base

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have app i want to connect to iphone app i have done code and also php code problem is that i am always getting Incorrect password alert view . I aam entering correct user name and password but again it displays error alert view

```
      NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserName=%@&UserPassword=%@",userNameTextField.text, userPasswordTextFiled.text];

     NSString *hostStr = @"http://www.myurl.com/emrapp/connect.php?";
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
     NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
     NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
     if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized "
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertsuccess show];
    [alertsuccess release];


    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"  message:@"Username or Password Incorrect"
                                                          delegate:self     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];

     }
```

And my server side code  is

```
    <?php
     $con = mysql_connect("emriphone.db.6420177.hostedresource.com","emriphone","Light12-");
   if (!$con)
    {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("emriphone", $con);

   $u=$_GET['UserName'];
   $pw=$_GET['UserPassword'];


   $query = sprintf("SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName='%s' AND  UserPassword='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($u),mysql_real_escape_string($pw));



  $login=mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());


  if(mysql_num_rows($login)==1){

   $row =mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
    echo 'YES'; exit;
   }

  else{
   echo'NO';exit;
  }

  mysql_connect($con);


  ?>
```

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720288/how-to-connect-with-sqlite-in-iphone

Comment: this is mine link dear but i am having same problem

Comment: the server output in string i am getting is @""; only so that's why i think it gives error can u help me out in thi s

Comment: What response your getting from server in string "serverOutput"?

Comment: @""; this when i nslog but when i direclty give username and password values to php script and match with database it returen YES

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Following Code

```
           NSString *data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserName=%@&UserPassword=%@",userNameTextField.text, userPasswordTextFiled.text];

           NSData *postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];  

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    // preaparing URL request to send data.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl.com/emrapp/connect.php?"];

            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            [request setTimeoutInterval:7.0];

NSURLResponse *response;// = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
NSError *error;// = [[NSError alloc] init;

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


     NSLog(@"Login response:is %@",str);
```

Comment: wait i am giving you result of this

Comment: Just try to ECHO your query and see what does it respondes?

Comment: this same as i told you printing space only because there is @"" in str

Comment: I don't know much about php about i think thier is some problem in php code?

Comment: Means anything you try to ECHO from server is blank?

Comment: SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName='' AND UserPassword=''NO echo of query

Comment: Echo this ->  $query and then exit.

Comment: i have added in comment the echo of querry

Comment: So query is correct? I cant see any values for UserName & UserPassword?

Comment: i am post the values to username and password from iphone app so may be there may be probelm in psoting

Comment: Try to NSLog .."data" means ur value of username and password and "postlength".

Comment: what is the output of postlength?