# How to connect to an Oracle Database from iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, database

I am new to iOS development and I am trying to make an application which should access a value from a Database using wi-fi and make changes in the front end according to the Value. I didn't find any inbuilt function provided by Apple to access oracle database. I found a link (http://odbcrouter.com/iosinstall) which was suggested by someone on stackoverflow.
But this needs to be purchased and I don't want to spend money just for learning purpose. Can somebody please tell me how to connect to any database from an iOS application?
Please also tell me if I am missing any inbuilt function provided by Apple.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I have heard many people say that it is not good to expose database directly to an iPhone app but I am saying that even I don't want to do this. I just want to know if a database can be connected through an iPhone application for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea.

I would not like the idea of a database exposed directly to the Internet this way.

Better to write and deploy a Java servlet to act as an intermediary between the device and the database.  It can authenticate the user, validate the inputs, bind the values, and interact with the database on the phone's behalf.

Comment: Maybe not a good idea to make an application and expose the database, but I am just curious and as told before just want to do it for learning purpose. So can you suggest me some solution with any inbuilt function or anything else?

Comment: I don't want to access the database through internet. I just want to know that can I connect my database with my iPhone app without spending any money

Comment: You can't use Oracle without spending money.  You'd be better off downloading and installing SQLite3.

Comment: Okay. Even that will do. I am not specific about any particular database. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Nope, Google is your friend.  You would use JDBC to connect to a database if this was Java.  See the search box at the top of this page?  Type "ios database" into it - you'll get stuff like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720288/how-to-connect-with-sqlite-in-iphone