# iphone data handling - Storage and retrival

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, core-data, plist

Dear All,
                      Now am developing offline examination kind of application, here it has different kind of sections and parts of questions for example it has Objective type question and answer , fill in the blanks, voice listening and answering, Read the paragraph and answer etc...

Here how to store this enormous data inside the application and what is the best way to implement it.

1. if i am converting all the data into XML means how to structure the questions and answers in XML. ?
2. if SQLlite or core data means how to structure the DB. ?
3. using plist..?

Any suggestions and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i decide to use HTML to load questions into uiwebview and sqlite for storing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in application with any way. But it depends on size of data.

If you store large data, then Sqlite is the best way.

For Sqlite,

- http://technologyservants.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46:shopping-list-an-iphone-sqlite-tutorial&catid=13:opinion&Itemid=21
- http://mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/
- http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/
- [Where's the best SQLite 3 tutorial for iPhone-SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716839/wheres-the-best-sqlite3-tutorial-for-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Thanks for your response Bhalara - By the my data structure is quit complex. is it possible store combination of answers ie in filling the blanks type of question there is no single answer is expected in may be in different sructure ..example if answer in 7.30 means user may enter time as numeric or text etc..

Comment: Also can you tell me the other posible way to implement local data storage... And why not xml..?

Comment: XML must be read entirely into memory before it can be used. If your data set is large, you can easily overwhelm the memory available on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Core Data with an SQLite persistent store. Core Data excels at handling both size and complexity in data models. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237943/creating-a-json-store-for-iphone/5249674#5249674) to a similar question for details

There is a learning curve to Core Data but once you understand it, it makes writing complex apps very easy.